# OTBI Time and Labour- Missing Time Card Entry

Tags: oracle, cloud, analysis, oracle-fusion-apps

In Oracle Fusion HCM, using the OTBI tool I'm trying to figure out how to display the missing time entries for an employee. I'm still new at this and there is such less documentation, so if anyone has any experience on this it would be of great help!

Thanks.

Comment: Entries which have not been entered for the date, i.e. not applied for leave, not a holiday, etc.